# POST url in JavaScript gets commented out

Tags: javascript, post

I'm trying to make a POST request in javascript, but URL's double slashes are treated as beginning of comment line... What is a good fix for that?

```
....
function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
    POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
    ....
```

Comment: put it in quotes: `"POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet"`

Comment: awesome, happy to help, good luck! I just posted the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the url in quotes it is a string and you need the quotes for JS to recognize it as such:

```
"https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store the url in a variable and pass in the post req. Instead can we try to fetch context path and create url at runtime instead of passing it completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
p4 = document.getElementById("p4");

p4.innerHTML = '<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto">Source</a>';
```

source is "a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto">Source</a"

then obviously you have to add < and > to the end of source

Comment: p4 = document.getElementById("p4");

  p4.innerHTML = '<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto">Source</a>';